# Question about booking flight to different city than destination city

Tags: air-travel, paris, russia

I was searching flights to Paris, and was shocked how much they were.  But I can fly to Russia, with a layover in Paris for nearly half the cost.
I know if I book to Russia I can just not get on the flight from Paris to Russia, but the question I have is how to fly from Paris to home when the originating city would not be Paris?  Does it matter that I wouldn't be on that first flight?

Comment: Beyond the rather significant issue of your remaining flights being cancelled after you skip the Paris-Russia segment, the airline likely won't allow you to board the flight to Paris unless you are eligible to enter Russia. If you need a visa to visit Russia, you'd need one before they'd let you fly to Paris.

Comment: Also, you might choose to get off the flight in Paris, but would your luggage do the same?

Comment: I do have a 3 year Russian visa, and I wouldn't be checking bags.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you check your bag, it will not be available in Paris. Ooops.

2) If you ask to check it only to Paris, they will know your plan and charge you the difference in airfare.  Ooops

3) If you use carry on bags only and skip your flight from Paris to Moscow, you will be marked as a no show and the balance of your booking will be cancelled.  Ooops.

4) In all three cases when you check onto your first flight they will want to see your Visa to enter Russia.  Ooops.

Comment: I won't be checking bags, and I do have a Russian visa.  As for missing the flight from Paris to Moscow, why would they cancel the rest of the booking I already paid for??  They sure don't do that if you miss a flight!

Comment: Because they know all the tricks to scam cheaper airfares and take appropriate action when people do such.